# Cors configurations doesn't work for spring webflux on Minikube

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, minikube

I have the below spring security configuration and a reactJs app calling a backend service,
It works fine when I run the ReactJs app outside minikube, but when I run it on minikube I got

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource

Spring security config

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
  return http
          .cors()
          .configurationSource(configurationSource())
          .and()
          .csrf().disable()
          .exceptionHandling()
          .authenticationEntryPoint((exchange, e) ->
                  Mono.fromRunnable(() -> exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))
          .accessDeniedHandler((exchange, e) ->
                  Mono.fromRunnable(() -> exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)))
          .and()
          .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
          .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
          .authorizeExchange()
          .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
          .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/signin").permitAll()
          .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/users").permitAll()
          .anyExchange().authenticated()
          .and().build();
}

private CorsConfigurationSource configurationSource() {
    var config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");

    return serverWebExchange -> config;
}
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: There is no response

Comment: I think it is blocked before even going to the server, maybe minikube blocks it ?

I tried this but didn't work

minikube --extra-config 'apiserver.cors-allowed-origins=["http://*"]' -v 10 start

Comment: Yeah if there’s no response, then it’s not a CORS issue. CORS never prevents the browser from receiving a response.

Comment: Is your calling the backend service behind a ingress ? If yes, post your ingress configuration.

Comment: I knew what is the issue, frontend is calling backend through ClusterIP service, and since the call comes from the browser, the service is not accessible, changed it to NodePort and it worked.

It was a misunderstanding, I thought that because both services are on the same cluster, ClusterIP should be fine, but actually the call comes from the browser